# Raspbian Stretch Lite: LightDM doesn't run

Tags: raspbian

After installing Raspbian Stretch Lite, I would like to install a GUI: Choose LightDM, but after reboot, when I insert my username and password (both correct), the system will come back at the same screen, asking me to insert the username and password again. How can I solve this?

Comment: How did you install the GUI? You may be missing dependencies.

Comment: GUI = Desktop but LightDM is a Login Manager!

Comment: @MatsK it's what raspi-config installs. What do suggest ?

Comment: ???? raspi-config doesnt install GUI/Desktop stuff. Reinstall the SD card.

Answer (score 2):

This did not work for me.

I did the above steps from both posts, but it still just restarts after entering username/password.
To fix this, I did the additional steps:

```
sudo apt-get install lxde --fix-missing
sudo apt-get install xinit
startx
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
systemctl get-default
```

And if it is not `graphical.target`:

```
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good article at  https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=133691 that explains what is need and several different options to add GUI to Raspbian Lite.

This work for me on Raspbian Stretch Lite:

1. Xorg `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends xserver-xorg -y`
2. Pixel GUI `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends raspberrypi-ui-mods lxterminal gvfs -y`
3. `sudo raspi-config` choose "3 Boot Options - Configure options for start-up", "B1 Desktop / CLI - Choose whether to boot into a des", "B4 Desktop Atologin Desktop GUI, automatically logged in as 'pi' user", "Ok", and reboot.